# .onAppear print before view is visible in TabVIew

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using TabView for making onboarding screens.

I will make example here.

I have this code for tabview:

```
TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { item in
                  Text("Test")
                    .onAppear {
                     print(item)
                   }
              }
            }    
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: pageIndex)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
```

When app is on run, in console is printed out 0, but when slide on next view, it shows 1 & 2.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PageTabViewStyle` is implemented using a scroll view, and it preloads pages into the scroll view for a smooth scrolling experience. That's why page 2 “appears” when you have only scrolled to page 1: it wants to be ready in case the user continues scrolling past page 1.

Use `onChange` instead of `onAppear` to watch for changes in `pageIndex`:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State var pageIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<3) { item in
                Text("page \(item)")
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: pageIndex)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
        .onChange(of: pageIndex) { newValue in
            print("page \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `onChange` will not fire for the initial appearance of page 0. If you need that, you could add an `onAppear` on the tab view:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State var pageIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<3) { item in
                Text("page \(item)")
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: pageIndex)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
        .onChange(of: pageIndex) { newValue in
            print("page \(newValue)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("page \(pageIndex)")
        }
    }
}
```